# How to check if a list of lists contains any of the elements from another list

Tags: nested-lists

I'm trying to make a sample lottery checker.
I'm using python.

```py
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,
    
    y = [[1,2,3,4,5,6] # 6 numbers hit
       ,[1,2,3,4,6,7] # 5 numbers hit
       ,[2,3,4,6,7,8] # 4 numbers hit
       ,[4,5,6,7,8,9] # 3 numbers hit
       ,[1,2,7,8,9,10] # 2 numbers hit
       ,[4,7,8,9,10,11] # 1 number hit
       ,[7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

output: (including the number of hits)

```py
        [1,2,3,4,5,6]  6 number hit
        [1,2,3,4,6,7]  5 numbers hit
        [2,3,4,6,7,8]  4 numbers hit
        [4,5,6,7,8,9]  3 numbers hit
        [1,2,7,8,9,10]  2 numbers hit
        [4,7,8,9,10,11]  1 number hit
```

I tried using the `any()` function but only returned true or false.
please help.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried and clarify what language you are using

Comment: which language ?

Comment: I’m using python sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```py
  x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
      
  y = [[1,2,3,4,5,6] # 6 numbers hit
      ,[1,2,3,4,6,7] # 5 numbers hit
      ,[2,3,4,6,7,8] # 4 numbers hit
      ,[4,5,6,7,8,9] # 3 numbers hit
      ,[1,2,7,8,9,10] # 2 numbers hit
      ,[4,7,8,9,10,11] # 1 number hit
      ,[7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

Code:

```py
  for ticket in y:
    print(ticket)
    count = 0
    for item in x:
      if item in ticket:
        count += 1
    print(count, " numbers hit!")
```

Output:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
6  numbers hit!
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
5  numbers hit!
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
4  numbers hit!
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3  numbers hit!
[1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
2  numbers hit!
[4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
1  numbers hit!
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
0  numbers hit!
```